# I can not download the package depthimage_to_laserscan on kinetic

Tags: ros, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've updated my list with the help of:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

I write :

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-depthimage_to_laserscan
```

And I get :

```
  E: Could not find package ros-kinetic-depthimage_to_laserscan
```

Plz help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236400/i-can-not-download-the-package-depthimage_to_laserscan-on-kinetic/) by [snowbars1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/27101/snowbars1234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The *ROS package* is called `depthimage_to_laserscan`, but the *debian package* is called `ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan`. The underscores (`_`) in the ROS package name are converted to dashes (`-`), as per Debian package naming guidelines.

---

Edit:

> ```
> E: Could not find package ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan
> ```

Looking at [ros_kinetic_default.html?q=depthimage](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=depthimage), it would seem the package has been released into Kinetic, but that the package hasn't been synced (copied) to the public package repositories. If you can wait a while, just wait: @tfoote will do a sync sometime in the coming weeks, which will make the package `apt-get`able.

If you can't wait, you have two options:

1. build from source: clone the [ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan](https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan.git) git repository, run a `rosdep install ..` step, then build your workspace
2. use the [wiki/ShadowRepository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) package repository. That repository will contain the version of the package that has been staged for the next sync (option 1). Understand though that using the shadow repository is considered 'advanced'.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [snowbars1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/27101/snowbars1234/) on 2016-06-08**:
E: Could not find package  ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan

**Comment by [snowbars1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/27101/snowbars1234/) on 2016-06-08**:
thx      .